# Elantech Touchpad not working at all

Tags: 14.04, drivers, touchpad, elantech

About a year ago I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and the touchpad never worked and as a result I never used ubuntu I just upgraded to 14.04 thinking it might work and the touchpad still doesn't work.

I have tried disabling the **acer wim**  files, editing the **xorg.conf**, using all the F Keys at the login screen and installing drivers with dkms that I found [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/161683989/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz)

When I run cat proc/bus/input/devices I find this

> I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
>   N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" 
>   P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0 
>   S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input10 U: Uniq= 
>   H: Handlers=mouse1 event6
>   B: PROP=5 B: EV=b B: KEY=e420 0 10000 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 B: ABS=6618000 11000003

Answer (score 0):

Hello Linuxers I see many problems with the Elantech Touchpad sites in the world. A clear solution was included in the kernel ubuntu 3.18. I installed ubuntu 14.10 (formerly the beta and now the clean final version) with an ultrabook ETPS / 2 Elantech Touchpad hardware that works in W8 but precariously as PS2 mouse in ubuntu. I downloaded the new kernel ubuntu 3.18, installed and after reboot everything is working. But, open System Settings> Mouse & Touchpad> Touchpad and see the visible section to enable a> Natural Scrolling

Comment: A guide on how to install Kernel 3.18 would be nice.